# Doctrine2 immutable entities and append only data structures

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I like the technique described by the Marco Pivetta at PHP UK Conference 2016 (https://youtu.be/rzGeNYC3oz0?t=2011), he recommends to **favour immutable entities** and instead of changing data structures - **appending them**. History of changes as a bonus is a nice thing to have for many different reasons, so I would like to apply this approach on my projects. Let's have a look at the following use case:

```
class Task {
    protected $id;
    /**
     * Status[]
     */
    protected $statusChanges;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->id = Uuid::uuid4();
        $this->statusChange = new ArrayCollection();
    }   

    public function changeStatus($status, $user){
        $this->statusChange->add(new Status($status, $user, $this);
    }

    public function getStatus()
    {
        return $this->statusChange->last();
    }
}

class Status {
    protected $id;
    protected $value;
    protected $changedBy;
    protected $created;

    const DONE = 'Done';

    public function __construct($value, User $changedBy, Task $task)
    {
        $this->id = Uuid::uuid4();
        $this->value = $value;
        $this->changedBy = $changedBy;
        $this->task = $task;
        $this->created = new \DateTime();
    }
}

$user = $this->getUser();
$task = new Task();
$task->changeStatus(Status::DONE, $user);
$taskRepository->add($task, $persistChanges = true);
```

All status changes I'm planning to persist in the MySQL database. So the association will be One(Task)-To-Many(Status).

**1) What is the recommended way of gettings tasks by current status? Ie. all currently opened, finished, pending tasks.**

```
$taskRepository->getByStatus(Status::DONE);
```

**2) What is your opinion on this technique, are there some disadvantages which may appear in the future, as the project will grow?**

**3) Where it is more practical to save status changes (as a serialized array in a Task field, or in a separate table?**

Thanks for opinions!

Answer (score 2):

I imagine this is going to get closed to some of it being based on opinion, just so you're aware.

That being said, I've been quite interested in the idea of this but I've not really looked into it a huge amount, but here's my thinking...

**1. Find By Status**
I think you would need to do some sort of sub query in the join to get the latest state for each task and match that. (I would like to point out that this is just guesswork from looking at SO rather than actual knowledge so it could be well off).

```
SELECT t, s
FROM t Task
LEFT JOIN t.status s WITH s.id = (
    SELECT s2.id
    FROM Status s2
    WHERE s2.created = (
        SELECT MAX(s3.created)
        FROM Status s3
        WHERE s3.task = t
    )
)
WHERE s.value = :status
```

*Or maybe just (provided the combined id & created fields are unique)...*

```
SELECT t, s
FROM t Task
LEFT JOIN t.status s WITH s.created = (
    SELECT MAX(s2.created)
    FROM Status s2
    WHERE s2.task = t
)
WHERE s.value = :status
```

**2 Disadvantages**
I would imagine that having to use the above type of queries for each repository call would require more work and would, therefore, be easier to get wrong. As you are only ever appending to the database it will only get bigger so storage/cache space may be an issue depending on how much data you have.

**3 Where To Save Status**
The main benefit of immutable entities is that they can be cached forever as they will never change. If you saved any state changes in a serialized field then the entity would need to be mutable which would defeat the purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I do:

## All the types of tables involved in my business

I organize my database in 4 types of tables:

- Log_xxx
- Data_xxx
- Document_xxx
- Cache_xxx

Any data I store falls in one of those 4 types of tables.

`Document_xxx` and `Data_xxx` are just for storing binary files (like PDFs of tariffs the providers send to me), and static data or super-slow-changing data (like the airports or countries or currencies in the world). They are not involved in the "main" of this explanation but worth mentioning them.

## Log tables

All my "domain events" and also the "application events" go to a `Log_xxx` table.

Log tables are write-once, never deleteable, and I must do backups of them. This is where the "history of the business" is stored.

For example, for a "task" domain object as you mention in your question, say that the task can be "created" and then altered later, I'd use:

- Log_Task_CreatedEvents
- Log_Task_ChangedEvents

Also I save all the "application events": Each HTTP request with some contextual data. Each command-run... They go to:

- Log_Application_Events

Never the domain can change unless there is an application that changes it (a command line, a cron, a controller attending an HTTP request, etc.). All the "domain events" have a reference to the application event that created them.

All the events, either domain events (like TaskChangedEvent) or the application events are absolutely immutable and carry several standard things like the timestamp at creation.

The "Doctrine Entities" have **no setters** so they can only be created and read. Never changed.

In the database I only have **one** relevant field. It is of type TEXT and represents the event in JSON. I have another field: WriteIndex which is autonumeric, is the primary key and is NEVER used by my software as a key. It is only used for backups and database control. When you have GBs of data sometimes you need to dump only "events starting at index XX".

Then for easiness, I have an extra field which I call "cachedEventId" which contains the very same "id" of the event, redundant to the JSON. This is why the field is named after "cached..." as it does not contain original data, it could be rebuilt from the event field. This is only for simplicity.

Although doctrine calls them "entities" those are not domain entities, they are domain value objects.

So, Log tables look like this:

```
INT      writeIndex;    // Never used by my program.
TEXT     event;         // Stores te event as Json
CHAR(40) cachedEventId; // Unique key, it acts really as the primary key from the point of view of my program. Rebuildable from the event field.
```

Sometimes I opt-in for having more cached fields, like the creation time-stamp. All those are not needed and only set there for convenience. All that should be extractable from the event.

## The Cache tables

- Then in the `Cache_xxx` I have the "accumulated data" data that can be "rebuilt" from the logs.

For example if I have a "task" domain object that has a "title" field, and a "creator", and a "due date", and the creator cannot be overwritten, by definition, and the title and due date can be re-set... then I'd have a table that looks like:

```
Cache_Tasks
    * CHAR(40) taskId
    * VARCHAR(255) title
    * VARCHAR(255) creatorName
    * DATE dueDate
```

## Write model

Then, when I create an task, it writes to 2 tables:

```
* Log_Task_CreatedEvents // Store the creation event here as JSON
* Cache_Tasks // Store the creation event as one field per column
```

Then, when I modify a task, it also writes to 2 tables:

```
* Log_Task_ChangedEvents // Store the event of change here as JSON
* Cache_Tasks // Read the entity, change its property, flush.
```

## Read model

To read the tasks, use the Cache_Tasks always.

They always represent the "latest state" of the object.

## Deleteability

All the `Cache_xxx` tables are deleteable and do not need to be backed up. Just replay the events in date order and you'll get the cached entities again.

## Sample code

I wrote this answer as "Task" as this was the question, but today for instance I've been working in assigning an "state" to the client's form-submissions. The clients just ask something via web and now I want to be able to "mark" this request as "new" or "processed" or "answered" or "mailValidated", etc...

I just created a new `change()` method to my `FormSubmissionManager`. It looks like this:

```
public function change( Id $formSubmissionId, array $arrayOfPropertiesToSet ) : ChangedEvent
{
    $eventId = $this->idGenerator->generateNewId();
    $applicationExecutionId = $this->application->getExecutionId();
    $timeStamp = $this->systemClock->getNow();

    $changedEvent = new ChangedEvent( $eventId, $applicationExecutionId, $timeStamp, $formSubmissionId, $arrayOfPropertiesToSet );

    $this->entityManager->persist( $changedEvent );
    $this->entityManager->flush();

    $this->cacheManager->applyEventToCachedEntity( $changedEvent );
    $this->entityManager->flush();

    return $changedEvent;
}
```

Note that I do 2 flushes. This is on purpose. In the case the "write-to-the-cache" fails I don't want to loose the changedEvent.

So I "store" the event, then I cache it to the entity.

The `Log_FormSubmission_ChangeEvent.event` field looks like this:

```
{
    "id":"5093ecd53d5cca81d477c845973add91e31a1dd9",
    "type":"hellotrip.formSubmission.change",
    "applicationExecutionId":"ff7ad4bd5ec6cebacc048650c866812ac0127ac2",
    "timeStamp":"2018-04-04T02:03:11.637266Z",
    "formSubmissionId":"758d3b3cf864d711d330c4e0d5c679cbf9370d9e",
    "set":
    {
        "state":"quotationSent"
    }
}
```

In the "row" of the cache I'll have the "quotationSent" in the column `state` so it can be queried normally from Doctrine even without the need of any Join.

[image: Sample of cached FormSubmission]

I sell trips. You can see there many de-normalized data coming from several sources, like for example the number of adults, kids and infants travelling (coming from the creation of the form submission itself), the name of the trip he requests (coming from a repository of trips) and others.

You can also see the latest-added field "state" at the right of the image. There may be like 20 de-mapped fields in the cached row.

## Answers to your questions

Q1) What is the recommended way of gettings tasks by current status? Ie. all currently opened, finished, pending tasks.

Query the cached table.

Q2) Are there some disadvantages which may appear in the future, as the project will grow?

When the project grows, intead of rebuilding the cache at the time of write, chich may be slow, you setup a queue system (for example a RabbitMq or AWS-SNS) and you just send to the queue a signal of "hey, this entity needs to be re-cached". Then you can return very quickly as saving a JSON and sending a signal to the queue is effort-less.

Then a listener to the queue will process all and every changes you make, and if re-caching is slow, you don't matter.

Q3) Where it is more practical to save status changes (as a serialized array in a Task field, or in a separate table?

Separate tables: A table for "status changes" (=log =events =value_objects, not entities), and another table for "tasks" (=cache =domain_entities).

When you make backups, place in super-secure place the backups of the logs.

Upon a critical failure, restore the logs=events and replay them to re-build the cache.

In symfony I use to create a `hellotrip:cache:rebuild` command that accepts as a parameter the cache I need to reconstruct. It truncates the table (deletes all cached data for that table) and re-builds it over again.

This is costly, so you only need to rebuild "all" when necessary. In normal conditions, your app should take care of having the caches up to date when there is a new event.

## Documents and Data

At the very beginning I mentioned the Documents and Data tables.

Time for it, now: You can use that information when rebuilding the caches. For example, you can "de-map" the airport name into the cached entity while in the events you may only have the airport code.

You can rather safely change the cache format as your business has more complex queries, having pre-calculated data. Just change the schema, drop it, re-build the cache.

The change-events, instead, will remain "exactly the same" so the code that gets the data and saves the event has not changed, reducing the risk of regression bugs.

Hope to help!

Comment: This approach is called [Event Sourcing](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html) and it is closely related to [CQRS](https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html). Nice practical explanation, though.

Comment: Interesting answer. How do you handle changes in the model? For example, consider a subscription website. Initially you design the system with just monthly payment option. Later you decide to add monthly and annual payment options for the sample plan. So now price information is separated from the `plan` table to a separate `pricing` table. Correspondingly the model is also updated. How will you process the older events without having the corresponding Model class?

Comment: This is a veeeery interesting question, @JoyceBabu - I am affraid a "short answer" here can be "too short" to be precise and illustrate all. Your comment qualifies a "full question" by itself. Why don't we do this? You create a brand new question in Stack Overflow mentioning that "in regards to this question xxx" (and you link to this one) "you wonder xxx" and you copy/edit your question (same specific example). That would allow me to develop a full answer plenty of detail (not abstract, but specific to your example). I'd more than happy to answer "long" to help understand how to handle that.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I wrote a detailed question, but just before submitting  I found that it has been already answered in several other similar questions on SO.

Comment: Thanks Joyce. To help other readers it'd be worth posting here in the comments the most relevant links to the questions you mention that solved you the problem. Sure they help other users in SO.